# How to delete some rows with comments from a CSV file to load data to DataFrame?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

There is a relatively big CSV file with data (around 80Mb). When I open it in MS Excel, I see that it contains 100 columns with many rows of data. However, the first row is not the column names, it's a web link. Furthermore, the last two rows are some comments.
So, now I want to load this data into pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Then I want to read a column called `Duration` (I see that it exists in CSV file) and delete a word `years` from it's values:

```
Duration = map(lambda x: float(x.rstrip('years')), df['Duration'])
```

It gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

If I open the file in MS Excel and delete the first row (a web link) and the last two rows (the comments), then the code works!

So, how can I clean this CSV file automatically in Python (to extract only columns with values)?

**Update:**
When I write `print df.head()`, it outputs:

```
have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

Do I need ot specify Type for all 100 columns? What if I don't know the types apriori.

**Update:**
I cannot attach the file, but as an example you can check [this one](https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action). 
Download the file 2015-2016.

Comment: You could drop the rows that don't contain 'years' and then remove the word and cast the dtype so something like `df.loc[df['Duration'].str.contains(['years']), 'Duration'].str.rstrip('years').astype(float)` should work

Comment: @EdChum: I think that the problem is with mixed types. Even if I only load the data and then type 'print df.head()', it already gives me an error: "have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False"

Comment: If the errant line numbers are known then you can skip them like the answers below

Comment: I think you need to show what the last 2 lines look like, a url will parse as a string object dtype but missing values will be interpreted as float to represent `NaN`

Comment: EdChum: See the update. I posted a link to a similar file. Then just type: df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')    print df.head()
and you will see the error message.

Comment: @EdChum: When I typed pd.read_csv(file,dtype=object) everything solved automatically... The first row and last rows are ignored. Do you know why this solution worked?

Comment: No idea, normally it will try to sniff the form of the csv and guess the number of columns, if it doesn't conform to the sniffed format it should fail so I'm surprised it worked and in fact your previous code worked as it should have borked once it saw the second line didn't match the first line format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some parameters in pd.read_csv() that you should use:

```
df = pdread_csv('myfile.csv', skiprows=1, skip_footer=2)
```

I looked at the link you provided in the comments and tried to import it.  I saw two mixed data types (for `id` and `desc`), so I explicitly set the dtype for these two columns.  Also, by observation, the footer contains 'Total', so I excluded any row starting with the letter `T`.  Other than the headers, valid rows should start with integers for the `id` column.  If there are other footers not starting with `T` that are introduced, this will throw an error when read.

If you first download and uncompress the `zip` file, you can proceed as follows:

```
file_loc = ...  # Specify location where you saved the unzipped file.
df = pd.read_csv(file_loc, skiprows=1, skip_blank_lines=True, 
                 dtype={'id': int, 'desc': str}, comment='T')
```

And this will strip out `year` or `years` from the `emp_length` column, although you are still left with text categories.

```
df['emp_length'] = df.emp_length.str.replace(r'( years|year)', '')
```

Comment: Is this solution generic? Imagin that I would unable to open the CSV file in Excel? How could I then understand that the problem is with the first and last rows? Furthermore, please check my update, when I talk about mixed types.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your data demonstrating the mixed types so others can reproduce the issue?  Without a sample of the file with the data causing the issues, it will be difficult to provide more guidance.  Fewer than ten rows (5 from top + 5 from bottom), and the relevant columns causing issues.

Comment: Great! Just one last question. How do you observe a footer from Python? Also, how (from Python) did you understand that the first row was a comment and it should be ignored?

Comment: There is no way to know how a file is parsed without without examining and creating some rules.  from within iPython, you can issue shell commands such as 'cat my_file.csv` to print the output, but I wouldn't recommend it.  I loaded it into Excel to view it.  There is also the `csv` module which you may want to explore.

Answer (score 1):

To skip the first line, you could use the `skiprows` option in `read_csv`. If the last two lines are not too tricky (i.e. that they cause some parsing errors), you could use `.iloc` to ignore them. Finally, a vectorized version of `rstrip` is available via the `str` attribute of the `Duration` column, assuming it contains strings.

See the following code for an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
content = StringIO("""http://www.example.com
col1,col2,Duration
1,11,5 years
2,22,4 years
3,33,2 years
# Some comments in the
# last two lines here.
""")
df = pd.read_csv(content, skiprows=1).iloc[:-2]
df['Duration'] = df.Duration.str.rstrip('years').astype(float)
print df
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2 Duration
0    1    11       5 
1    2    22       4 
2    3    33       2
```

If reading speed is not a concern, you can also use the `skip_footer=2` option in `read_csv` to skip the last two lines. This will cause `read_csv` to use the Python parser engine instead of the faster C engine.

Comment: Is it possible to transform it into a more generic solution? What happens if I don't know the exact value for skiprows? (e.g. what if I cannot open the file in any editor due to its size)

Comment: Please see my update when I give a link to the identical file (not the one I use, but with a similar issue).

Comment: I think there is no good reason to put in efforts to make this solution "generic". The ways to create invalid csv files is infinite, unless there are more constraints on the types of invalid-ness (e.g. contains an unknown number of URLs in the top rows? In which case, you can write a function to run through the file to find the first row that does not look like a URL. This is the number of rows to skip).

Comment: When I typed pd.read_csv(file,dtype=object) everything solved automatically... The first row and last rows are ignored. Do you know why this solution worked?

Comment: With ``dtype=object``, I think all the values will be stored as string, even if the column is purely numeric. Not sure if this is the result you would want in the end.